# how to add register user contacts in android app same as whatsapp?

Tags: android

I want to add contact list of registered user in my android app.
for eg. many user registered to whatsapp? when we install it then all save contacts shown in whats up contact list.How it will happened.I am new in android development please give me solution.

Comment: what you did till now? any code you tried?

Comment: i take my cell contact only.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all contacts from the device
2. Send to your server
3. Compare with your list of registered users (from your DB)
4. Return back the registered list of users to that device
5. List as you wish in your app